# Converting list to dictionary

Tags: python

I have list which contains data as below

```
Listing = ['abc:123', 'bcd:234', 'def:456'...]
```

This above listing I derived it from a text file which has data similar to above.

How to convert the above to dictionary?

```
D = [abc:123, Bcd:234, Def:456]
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary you wrote there, a dictionary looks like `D = {"abc":123, "Bcd":234, "Def":456}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a generator expression and the `split()` method:

```
D = dict(i.split(":", 1) for i in Listing)
```

If there are some items that don't have the `x:y` format and you want to ignore them, you can add a conditional:

```
D = dict(i.split(":", 1) for i in Listing if ":" in i)
```

Comment: Not downvoter but generally some people dislike when user answers low effort questions, since it will encourage others to ask similar low effort questions (which shouldn't be part of SO).

Comment: As it turns out I happen to disagree with that opinion.

Comment: @MooingRawr Isn't it better to just downvote the question? If the answer is good (like this one is), it just discourages answerers to answer questions, IMHO.

Comment: Once again, not the downvoter, I'm just pointing out a habit I notice on this site.

Comment: @Amber : thanks for the answer.  It really worked.I know this a very basic question it's been a month i just started python, so was stuck at this point so thought to ask on stack overflow. Will try in future not to try ask such low effort questions in future.

Comment: @RahulGupta Awesome! It's great if you accept the answer that works for you by clicking that check mark :D

Answer (score -1):

You can split each line and create a dictionary. This is a bit less Pythonic then Amber's answer, and it does roughly the same thing.

```
def listToDictionary(list):
  dictionary = {}

  for item in list:
    key, value = item.split(":")
    dictionary[key] = value

  return dictionary

print(listToDictionary(['abc:123', 'bcd:234', 'def:456']))
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/repls/WhoppingSpicyAfricanwildcat)

Comment: A generator expression doesn't duplicate the list either.

Comment: @Amber Oh! Awesome! Didn't know that. I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
D = {item.split(":")[0]: item.split(":")[1] for item in Listing}
```

This has the downside of claling .split two times.

Or if you know each item in the list is 7 char's long:

```
D = {item[:3]: item[4:] for item in Listing}
```